# Redirecting SSL www.* to non www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine  On
Redirect 301 /a    https://website.com/b
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.website\.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My `/a -> /b` redirect works, but the www. to non-www. redirect isn't being applied.  How do I correctly set this up?

Comment: There is no such thing as `HTTPS_HOST`.

Comment: @CBroe dropping that `S` did the trick.  Thanks!